# what is the best practice for getting JSON from other activity

Tags: java, android, json, android-intent, parcelable

i was wondering what is the best practice to get a JSON and to display it, from one to activity(with NO GUI) to an other activity(WITH GUI),i found couple methods ranging from just passing the jsonobject in the PutExtra, to making a Parcable class and then passing it as an PutExtraParacble. but i found it incomplete because getting a json can vary from 1milisec to 5 whole second's(going to have samll and huge Jsons) so when i use the parcable class method and then get the extras from my MainActivity i can get a null pointer exception from the parcable class...
here is the importent code parts:

```
     APIcontroller.getCardAPI("http://www.somesite.com/feeds/GetPlace", params);
    Intent getJson = getIntent();
    CardContent cardContent = (CardContent) getJson.getParcelableExtra("cardContent");
    jsonArryCard = cardContent.getJsonArray();
```

and then in the APIcontroller class:

```
 public void getCardAPI(String WSaddress,RequestParams params) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(WSaddress,params, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            try {
                String respons = null;
                try {
                    respons = responseBody == null ? null : new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(respons);
                JSONArray resultsArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("places");
                JSONObject taskObject = null;
                for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
                    // the JSON object in position i
                    taskObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    String temp = (String) taskObject.get("UserName");
                    Log.e("String test", temp);

                }
                CardContent cardContent = new CardContent(resultsArray);
                Intent sendjson = new Intent(APIController.this, MainRegisterdActivity.class); 
                sendjson.putExtra("cardContent", (Parcelable) cardContent);

                startActivity(sendjson);
                MainRegisterdActivity.class);
                Log.e("onSuccess", String.valueOf(taskObject));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

i think its because the asyntask is still runing so it dosent have a value when its goes to the next code line.. should i just use broadcast reciver or is there any other way?
thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking right! I had the same experience.In my opinion, the best way is to use broad cast receiver. Another untidy solution is to take `getCardAPI` function out of your class and place it in activity with GUI and place rest of your code in `getCardAPI` function.Thus,you are sure that value is set and rest of your code will be executed, but it is **not** recommended!